# Tensorboard ValueError no recognised filesystem for prefix E

Tags: python, tensorboard

In Python 3.8 on Windows we have been using foward-slash as the path component separator without issue until now. For example `Path('E://Data/rf').mkdir(exist_ok=True)` makes the directory `E:\\Data\rf`

But initialising [torch.utils.tensorboard.writer.SummaryWriter](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensorboard.html#torch.utils.tensorboard.writer.SummaryWriter) throws an odd error:

- `SummaryWriter(log_dir=r'E:\\Data\rf')` works fine, but
- `SummaryWriter(log_dir=r'E://Data/rf')` throws the error

> ValueError: No recognized filesystem for prefix E

Why is tensorboard behaving differently from the rest of Python?

(N.B. Is there a package that unifies OS paths in Python? Neither `os.path` nor `Pathlib` offer any conversion or abstraction functions.)

Here's the full stack, after our code hands off to tensorboard

```
File "C:\Users\timregan\Miniconda3\envs\Talia38\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\tensorboard\writer.py", line 225, in __init__  
self._get_file_writer()  
File "C:\Users\timregan\Miniconda3\envs\Talia38\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\tensorboard\writer.py", line 255, in _get_file_writer  
self.file_writer = FileWriter(self.log_dir, self.max_queue,  
File "C:\Users\timregan\Miniconda3\envs\Talia38\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\tensorboard\writer.py", line 65, in __init__  
self.event_writer = EventFileWriter(  
File "C:\Users\timregan\Miniconda3\envs\Talia38\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\summary\writer\event_file_writer.py", line 76, in __init__  
if not tf.io.gfile.exists(logdir):  
File "C:\Users\timregan\Miniconda3\envs\Talia38\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\io\gfile.py", line 613, in exists  
return get_filesystem(filename).exists(filename)  
File "C:\Users\timregan\Miniconda3\envs\Talia38\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\io\gfile.py", line 81, in get_filesystem  
raise ValueError("No recognized filesystem for prefix %s" % prefix)  
ValueError: No recognized filesystem for prefix E
```

Comment: It could be tensorboard explicitly checking for `"://"` in the path: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/34741671ccd49f37ab58e9a064e09bddbc841487/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/io/gfile.py#L72

Comment: Thanks @jakub, I can see why that code might fail. I've added it as an issue [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/4080)

Comment: I wonder if Tensorboard is expecting a [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) filepath, which has `://`. You can try using [`pathlib.Path().as_uri()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.as_uri).